# Dictionary inside of for loop results in TypeError, outside of for loop works fine

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok so basically what I'm trying to do is a search through all of the values in a column in an excel file and then mark them green if they match any of the data values in a separate text file.

I apologize if my code is hard to read, still very much a beginner.

So the below will run fine and prints the dictionary "dictIPExcel" with no issue:

```
dictIPExcel = {}
##############IMPORTANT CHANGE HERE, FILE NAME########################
#Change file name here to suit your file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
#Copy sheet name here
sheet = wb.active

#What font color to change to below

greenFill = PatternFill(start_color='0000B200', end_color='0000B200', fill_type='solid')

#This will create a list containing every line in the below txt file
IPlist = open('No Config or Denied devices.txt').read().split('\n')

#Loops through A19-A100, gathering the value in each row into dictIPExcel
for t in range(19,100):
    dictIPExcel["A{0}".format(t)] = sheet['A'+ str(t)].value
print dictIPExcel
sheetz = wb.sheetnames

for a in sheetz:
    sheet = a
    dictIPExcel = {}

    for l in range(19,100):
        for x,y in dictIPExcel.items():
            for z in IPlist:
                if y == z:
                    print "match"
                    sheet[x].fill = greenFill
wb.save('textCopy4.xlsx')
```

However, if I move the "dictIPExcel" to within the second for loop, it throws a 'TypeError: Strings must be integers.' Now from what I understand this means that it is basically not ok with having the 'A50' for example be the index in the dictionary. My question is why does this work outside of that loop? The data  index in the dictionary isn't changing outside of the loop vs. inside, yet the error is only thrown inside. Code with loop inside:

```
for a in sheetz:
    sheet = a
    dictIPExcel = {}
    for t in range(19,100):
        dictIPExcel["A{0}".format(t)] = sheet['A'+ str(t)].value
    for l in range(19,100):
        for x,y in dictIPExcel.items():
            for z in IPlist:
                if y == z:
                    print "match"
                    sheet[x].fill = greenFill
```

Below is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:..\testing.py", line 49, in <module>
    dictIPExcel["A{0}".format(t)] = sheet['A'+ str(t)].value
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there anything I can do to allow this to run within the loop? Or perhaps there is a better way of going about what I am trying to do in going through every sheet and highlighting matching data?

Comment: I think this is actually in the `.format` part of your string comprehension, though I'm not sure why. If you're using Python 2 use `("A%i" % (t))` for the string, or just use `"A" + str(t)` like you had before. Otherwise, in Python 3 you need to specify the variable in the string, `"A{0}".format(0=t)` although variable names can't start with a numerical value. Also, take a look at the answer by @keredson, it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the final working setup that worked for me is as follows for anyone who may have a similar issue in the future. I think both of the above answers were right, however the main problem was I was forgetting to call the .get_sheet_by_name() function:

```
for a in sheetz:
    sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name(a)
    dictIPExcel = {}
    for t in range(19,100):
        dictIPExcel["A{0}".format(t)] = sheet2['A'+ str(t)].value
    for l in range(19,100):
        for x,y in dictIPExcel.items():
            for z in IPlist:
                if y == z:
                    print "match"
                    sheet2[x].fill = greenFill
wb.save('Copy.xlsx')
```

With this change the script worked and I now have an appropriately greenified workbook. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this has anything to do w/ `dictIPExcel`.  The error indicates the variable `sheet` is a `str`, not a `dict` as you're treating it.

Look at:

```
#Copy sheet name here
sheet = wb.active
```

Then you're overwriting it here:

```
for a in sheetz:
    sheet = a
```

With what I assume is a `str` based on `sheetz = wb.sheetnames`.

This is a common misunderstanding about python.  For loops don't have their own variable namespace, and inner vars can clobber variables outside their scope.  For example:

```
>>> for i in range(5): pass
... 
>>> print i
4
>>>
```

If you use a different variable in your loop (`sheet_name`?), you should be good.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case (the correct one)

```
sheet = wb.active
```

so the `sheet` is a *dictionary.*

In the second (incorrect) case,

```
sheet = a   # for a in sheetz, where  sheetz = wb.sheetnames
```

the `sheet` is a **list** (so it need *integer* indices).

Answer (score 0):

sheetz are list of sheet names, which are strings. You need get the handle using `wb.get_sheet_by_name`

```
for a in sheetz:
    sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name(a)
    dictIPExcel = {}
    for t in range(19,100):
        dictIPExcel["A{0}".format(t)] = sheet['A' + str(t)].value
```